# What does interface state "configuring" mean?

Tags: networking, linux-networking, systemd-networkd

My `systemd-networkd-wait-online.service` fails. When I take a look:

```
% networkctl
IDX LINK             TYPE               OPERATIONAL SETUP     
  1 lo               loopback           carrier     unmanaged 
  2 eth0             ether              routable    configuring
% ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0a:e9:d9:16:22:4e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet xx.xx.xx.xx/24 brd xx.xx.xx.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 2794sec preferred_lft 2794sec
```

It seems to be stuck at that state `configuring` but everything seems to work just fine. What does this state mean, and how do I get it out of it?

Added: Content of `/etc/systemd/network/50-ubos-eth0.network`:

```
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
DHCP=yes
```

Comment: What does systemd-networkd log? What is your networkd configuration?

Comment: This is an EC2 instance running UBOS (Arch derivative), initialized with cloud-init. Nothing in the journal that sticks out. Adding network configuration to the post.